# Why is grep "-c" with 0 count exits program with status code -1

Tags: bash, count, grep

why is that when `grep -c` returns `0`, script fails with '-1' exit code. This happens only when `set -o errexit` is set.

## Copy/Paste on a bash shell

```
cat <<'EOT' > /tmp/foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function bash_traceback() {
  local lasterr="$?"
  set +o xtrace
  local code="-1"
  local bash_command=${BASH_COMMAND}
  echo "Error in ${BASH_SOURCE[1]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]} ('$bash_command' exited with status $lasterr)"
  if [ ${#FUNCNAME[@]} -gt 2 ]; then
    # Print out the stack trace described by $function_stack
    echo "Traceback of ${BASH_SOURCE[1]} (most recent call last):"
    for ((i=0; i < ${#FUNCNAME[@]} - 1; i++)); do
    local funcname="${FUNCNAME[$i]}"
    [ "$i" -eq "0" ] && funcname=$bash_command
    echo -e "  $i: ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}:${BASH_LINENO[$i]}\t$funcname"
    done
  fi
  echo "Exiting with status ${code}"
  exit "${code}"
}

test_redirecting_of_stdout_stderr() {

    # Exit program when error found
    set -o errexit

    # Exit program when undefined variable is being used
    set -o nounset

    local up_count
    up_count=$(ls | grep -c NOTHING_MATCHED)
    echo "up_count: $up_count"
}

# provide an error handler whenever a command exits nonzero
trap 'bash_traceback' ERR

set -o errtrace

test_redirecting_of_stdout_stderr

EOT

bash /tmp/foo.sh
```

## Output

```
debian:~/my-mediawiki-docker$ bash /tmp/foo.sh
Error in /tmp/foo.sh:31 ('up_count=$(ls | grep -c NOTHING_MATCHED)' exited with status 255)
Traceback of /tmp/foo.sh (most recent call last):
  0: /tmp/foo.sh:31     up_count=$(ls | grep -c NOTHING_MATCHED)
  1: /tmp/foo.sh:40     test_redirecting_of_stdout_stderr
Exiting with status -1
debian:~/my-mediawiki-docker$
```

Comment: Let me echo chepner's link to [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: (BTW, the use to which `echo -e` is being put would be more reliable -- working in a wider array of valid bash runtime configurations -- if you used, say, `printf '  %s: %s:%s\t%s\n' "$i" "${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}" "${BASH_LINENO[$i]}" "$funcname"` instead).

Answer (score 8):

`grep` reports "failure" if it fails to find any matching lines. Here's `man grep`:

```
EXIT STATUS
       The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.
```

If you want to allow a command to exit with non-zero without terminating the script during `errexit`, use `|| true`:

```
up_count=$(ls | grep -c NOTHING_MATCHED) || true
```

Comment: The `:` synonym for `true` is idiomatic in this usage; thus, one might often see `foo ||:` serving the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Setting this option assumes that any non-zero exit status from a command is a fatal error. That is not the case with `grep`, which uses a non-zero exit status simply to indicate a failure to match. This allows you to write code like

```
if grep "$pattern" file.txt; then
    echo "Found a match"
else
    echo "Found no match"
fi
```

`errexit` specifically ignores the exit status of a command used in an `if` condition like the above, but cannot know whether a line like

```
up_count=$(ls | grep -c NOTHING_MATCHED)
```

is "allowed" to have a non-zero exit status. The workaround is to protect such commands with

```
# As an aside, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
up_count=$(ls | grep -c NOTHING_MATCHED) || :
```

In general, it is better to do your own error checking than to rely on `errexit`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 for more information.